# MySQL view not properly handling new table field

Tags: mysql, view

I have a really simple view that joins all fields from `table A` and a single field from `table B`

```
create view view_tables

select table_a.*
        , table_b.some_id
    from table_a inner join table_b on table_a._id = table_b.a_id;
```

in this way a query like

```
select * 
from view_tables
where some_id = 100;
```

can be used.

However, when a new field was added to `table_a`, it's in the result set of `view_tables` when queried against, but if the query uses the `new_field` in the where clause

```
select * 
    from view_tables
    where some_id = 100
    and new_field = 200';
```

it returns an error

```
Error Code 1054.  Unknown column 'new_field' in 'where clause'
```

I literally had to drop and re-add the view - no changes to the view definition.  This concerns me in a production environment that new fields will not be properly handled.

I don't want to have to drop and re-add affected views when a new field is added to a table.

> Under what circumstances would this occur and how do I prevent it from happening?

Might it be a timing situation where if enough time elapses, the view work work correctly?  Possibly a cache that has not yet been refreshed?

**MySQL v5.7.22**

Comment: Note that views have no access to underlying indexes in MySQL, rendering their utility questionable.

Comment: @Strawberry  Thanks, that's good to know.

Comment: don't you have new_field in both tables ?

Comment: @ThomasG    No.  The new field was only added to table_a.  Therefore full qualification is not necessary.  But even so, it still fails with the same error.